# Saving off an element's CSS and reapply later

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to save off all CSS that is 'currently' applied to an element, then later reapply it? I am working on a sticking table header, and when I i change `position:fixed` it loses all the applied styles. I currently save off the column widths and reapply to the table header with:

```
            $('#tableHeader').css({
                position:'fixed',
                width:$('#tablePanel').width(),
                top:$('#top').height(),
            });

            $('.column1Value').width(col1Width);
            $('#col1').width(col1Width);

            $('.column2Value').width(col2Width);
            $('#col2').width(col2Width);

            $('.column3Value').width(col3Width);
            $('#col3').width(col3Width);

            $('.column4Value').width(col4Width);
            $('#col4').width(col4Width);

            $('.column5Value').width(col5Width);
            $('#col5').width(col5Width);

            $('.column6Value').width(col6Width);
            $('#col6').width(col6Width);

            $('.column7Value').width(col7Width);
            $('#col7').width(col7Width);
```

This make the columns the correct size and line up closely, but there is extra padding or margin being applied from somewhere I can't completely figure out (bootstrap probably), and this makes the headers and columns not line up. I was hoping for something like:

`var savedCSS = $('#table').css();` and retrieve it like `$('#table').css(savedCSS)`

Comment: To help you find out where things are coming from, use the developer console of a browser like chrome to find the "computed" styles. These will tell you what rule finally took precedence and where it came from.

Comment: @Klors , that is where I found bootstrap margins. When I change them in developer tools, it looks correct. When I *actually* change the style, it does not change. This leads me to believe it is being styled in more than one place and it might be easier to save off styles and reapply. Thank you for the comment!

Comment: So you're going to the Computed tab and seeing what file the final property value came from and then changing it in that file, but it's not applying?

Comment: @Klors , that is correct. It says  it is the `.row {
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}` from bootstrap.css. When I remove it, it does not help.

Comment: Removing it will allow any other rule that may have been overwritten by that rule to then apply. To overwrite it you need to specify the style, depending on the style it may have a "default" value that you can set like `auto` or you could specify the value you actually want. To do that without editing the bootstrap style itself (which would be lost if you ever upgraded bootstrap, etc) you need to apply a style that is as specific (http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg) and that overwrites the styles you need, or that has `!important`.

Comment: As for copying and then re-applying, I think you'd have to specify the individual css properties one-by one and save them as an object to re-apply.

Comment: @Klors, I am overriding the styles with custom CSS, but the problem still does not change. Is removing a styl in the developer tab the same as applying `0px` in CSS?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69320/discussion-between-klors-and-jordan-j-d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save off the individual styles that you are interested in one by one and then re-apply them later using the `jQuery("selector").css("styleName")` method that you alluded to, but I don't think there's an easy way to do them all at once. It's not impossible, but wouldn't be very efficient and probably wouldn't actually give you the result you want, once the element is in its new position.

After the discussion, we found that the sizing issue wasn't really due to the styles, but due to the element that the `width` was being calculated from.

When the element is positioned normally in the page-flow, it uses its most recent positioned parent's width and then takes off margin to find the width of the child content.

When the element is removed from the page flow, its width is then independent of the parent. So to get the two to match up, record the parent's width rather than the element itself and set the width to match the parent, instead of trying to maintain the element's width.